# How to use RANK OVER PARTITION BY to create rankings based on two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have duplicate records caused by data inconsistency. I am trying to take only one record for each patient (taking the latest record), who each have dozens of duplicate records due to address changes.

When I run the code below, each record in my table seems to be assigned a rank of 1. How can I assign rankings specific to each Patient ID?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     PATIENT_ID
     ,ADDRESS_START_DATE
     ,ADDRESS_END_DATE
     ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PATIENT_ID ,ADDRESS_START_DATE ORDER BY ADDRESS_START_DATE DESC) AS Ind
FROM Member_Table
;
```

Comment: Remove ADDRESS_START_DATE from PARTITION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't partition by the `address_start_date` if you're ordering by it:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
     PATIENT_ID
     ,ADDRESS_START_DATE
     ,ADDRESS_END_DATE
     ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PATIENT_ID ORDER BY ADDRESS_START_DATE DESC) AS Ind
FROM Member_Table
;
```

Comment: I see, that's a good rule of thumb to know. Doing it this way will assign all identical PATIENT_ID - ADDRESS_START_DATE pairs identical ranks, correct? I have duplicates across that combination as well...

Comment: @bhbennett3 . . . `rank()` assigned the same ranking.  `row_number()` would also return a distinct value for the enumeration, even when there are ties.